# Laravel Eloquent collect paired items

Tags: php, laravel, aggregate

I'm looking for a way to aggregate a collection of `eloquent` users pairs in Laravel. `[[user][partner]]`

I've got the following users table structure

```
[id] [name] [partner_id]
```

A user entity has matching partner_ids or null (if no partner exists)

```
| id | name          | partner_id |
+----+---------------+------------+
| 1  | John Doe      | 3          |
| 2  | J Random User | NULL       |
| 3  | Jane Doe      | 1          |
| .. | ...           | ...        |
```

Expected result:

```
[
  [
    { "id": 1, "name": "John Doe", "partner_id": 3 },
    { "id": 3, "name": "Jane Doe", "partner_id": 1 },
  ],
  [
    { "id": 2, "name": "J Random User", "partner_id": null },
  ]
]
```

I don't get how I fetch the users once and aggregate the `$users`-collection into pairs in my controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;

class PairController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        $collection = collect();

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $myself = $user->id;
            $partner = $user->partner_id;

            // ... ???
        }

        return $collection->unique();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out with a solution? I'm stuck in my brain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it's not perfect but it may be a place to start.

```
// Return all users and group them by their id
$grouped_users = User::all()->groupBy('id');

// Now loop through each user on record
User::all()->each(function ($user) use (&$grouped_users) {
    if ($user->partner_id && $grouped_users->has($user->partner_id)) {
        $partner_id = $user->partner_id;

        // Push the user model into our grouped collection
        $grouped_users[$partner_id]->push($user);

        // Remove the id for the current user from the collection
        $grouped_users->forget($user->id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below.

```
    public function index()
    {
        $usersWithoutPartner = collect();
        $usersWithPartner = collect();
        User::chunk(100, function ($users) use ($usersWithoutPartner, $usersWithPartner) {
            foreach ($users as $user) {
                if ($user->partner_id == null) {
                    $usersWithoutPartner->push($user);
                } else {
                    $usersWithPartner->push($user);
                }
            }
        });

        $finalCollection = collect();
        $finalCollection->push($usersWithoutPartner);
        $finalCollection->push($usersWithPartner);
        return $finalCollection;
}
```

Comment: Chunking is a good idea! Your collections may need to be included using `&` to allow them to be written to